# A (G-rated) graphic novel with a picture of purple tentacles coming out of a door on the cover

Tags: story-identification, comics, parallel-universe

I'm trying to find a graphic novel about two kids, a boy and a girl, who moved to an old family house because they couldn't afford where they were living anymore. In the house, they discovered a doorway to another world, which they went through to have adventures. At one point there was a flashback showing how the kids' father died when the whole family was in the car. The car went over a cliff and they all managed to get out of it in time except the dad.

Most obvious thing I can remember is the purple tentacles coming out of the door on the cover. I'm pretty sure I also remember a talking bunny who flew some kind of ship and possibly had a big gun.

Ring any bells for anybody?

Comment: +1 for the "G-rated" qualifier. It was both funny (for the fact that including it was necessary) and useful (avoiding an "*x* cannot be unseen" moment).

Comment: Nothing with tentacles stays G-rated for long.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sounds like [Amulet Stonekeeper](http://www.scholastic.com/amulet/) by Kazu Kibuishi.

[image: Book cover]